# Group items by 2 columns

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by

Let's say we have a Sqlite table containing:

```
name;city;age;id
Alice;New-York;25;13782749
Eve;Chicago;23;1938679
Bob;New-York;25;824697624
```

How to group by `h=CONCAT(city,age)`:

```
h;name;id
group1;Alice;13782749
group1;Bob;824697624
group2;Eve;1938679
```

Instead of `group1`, `group2`, it's ok to have `1`, `2`, or even a hash `f68ac46`, `c3155a0` for each group.

The closest I could get is:

```
select (city||age) as h, * from mytable order by h;
```

but I'd like a group number or a hash instead, and not display `city||age`  (which in my real case can be long).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could enumerate the groups using `dense_rank()`:

```
select dense_rank() over (order by city, age) as grpnum, name, id
from t;
```

Comment: Wonderful @GordonLinoff, it works, even with Sqlite! I edited the question at the end with a slight modification, would you have an idea for this?

Comment: @Basj . . . You should ask the revised question as a *new question*.  It is quite different.