# Group items by 2 columns or similarity with another column

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, sql-order-by

Let's say we have a Sqlite table containing:

```
name;city;age;id;foo
Alice;New-York;25;13782749;12
Eve;Chicago;23;1938679;34
Bob;New-York;25;824697624;56
Jack;Denver;30;239679163;12
Simone;Denver;30;1687631;99
```

**How to group by `h=CONCAT(city,age)` *but also* add in the group the users that have a column `foo` identical to someone in the group?**

As seen in [Group items by 2 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69261892/group-items-by-2-columns), here is how to group by `h`:

```
select dense_rank() over (order by city, age) as grpnum, name, id from t;
```

How to add this second condition on `foo`?

Example: here Alice and Bob are in the same `group1` because they have identical `h=CONCAT(city,age)`, but Jack should *also* be in `group1` because he has same foo value as Alice: `12`. Simone has same `CONCAT(city,age)` than Jack, therefore she is in the same group as Jack,  in `group1` as well.

Comment: And if there were another person who was from Denver and 30, would they be in their own group?  Or with Jack with the others?

Comment: @GordonLinoff With Jack and the others. If `foo` is similar, then they are grouped together.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I added an example in the question with another user Simone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is much trickier.  This is a graph-walking problem, which requires a recursive CTE (Common Table Expression).

The idea is to generate all the edges between names.  Then use a recursive CTE to visit all connected nodes (`name`s), avoiding visiting existing ones.

Here is one method:

```
with recursive edges as (
      select distinct t1.name as name1, t2.name as name2
      from t t1 join
           t t2
           on t1.city = t2.city and t1.age = t2.age or
              t1.foo = t2.foo
     ),
     cte as (
      select name1, name2, min(name1, name2) as first_name,
             ',' || name1 || ',' || name2 || ',' as visited
      from edges
      union all
      select cte.name1, e.name2, min(cte.first_name, e.name2),
             visited || e.name2 || ','
      from cte join
           edges e
           on e.name1 = cte.name2
      where visited not like '%,' || e.name2 || ',%'
     )
select t.*, cte.grpnum
from t join
     (select name1, min(first_name), dense_rank() over (order by min(first_name)) as grpnum
      from cte
      group by name1
     ) cte
     on t.name = cte.name1;
```

And [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=218158349e6d71469b99a611d77c14e5) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you very much Gordon, I'm going to study this deeply to understand how it works.